# Securing RESTful APIs using WSO2 IS

Tags: rest, security, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm developing a number of RESTful API's and they are consumed by another web applications.

1. What is the most secure protocol (SAML2 or oAuth2) for use in this scenario ?
2. What is the best approach to secure RESTful web services using WSO2
       Identity Server ?

Comment: Hope this will be helpful http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/

Answer (score 0):

First differentiate OAuth and SAML, its not about what is more secure but what is most suitable for your scenario. SAML is mainly used if you need to have SSO (Single Sign On), Federation and Identity Management. OAuth is a authorization resource standard [1].

You can simply secure REST APIs by using only WSO2 APIM which has OAuth out of box. You can easily follow APIM Quick Start guide and setup it [2]. If you need to achieve more requirements like SSO and federation, you need to integrate WSO2 IS [3]

[1] https://dzone.com/articles/saml-versus-oauth-which-one

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Quick+Start+Guide

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0